# Twitter API V2 - Get all tweets/Feed from Twitter List

Tags: python, response, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I have a twitter list where I want to scrape every tweet which occurs within this list with a Twitter API V2 research account.
Here is the link to the list: https://mobile.twitter.com/i/lists/912241909002833921

Following query gives me the tweets of the account which has created this list:

```
import tweepy
from twitter_authentication import bearer_token
import time
import pandas as pd
import time

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

start = time.time()
csu_tweets = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, 
                                     query = f'from:wahl_beobacher -is:retweet lang:de',
                                     user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                                     tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
                                     expansions = 'author_id',
                                     start_time = '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
                                     end_time = '2022-12-06T00:00:00Z'):
    time.sleep(1)
    csu_tweets.append(response)

end = time.time()
print(f"Scraping needed {(end - start)/60} minutes.")
print(len(csu_tweets))
```

But I want to get the feed from this list, so how do I have to change the query?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `get_list_tweets` method mentioned in the [Tweepy Docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_list_tweets) and start off with one page of 100 tweets in a list:

```
import tweepy
from twitter_authentication import bearer_token
import time
import pandas as pd
import time

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

start = time.time()
csu_tweets = []

response = client.get_list_tweets(
    id=912241909002833921,
    user_fields=['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
    tweet_fields=['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
    expansions='author_id',
    max_results=100)

end = time.time()
print(f"Scraping needed {(end - start)/60} minutes.")

for res in response.data:
    csu_tweets.append(res)

print(len(csu_tweets))
```

You can then implement the pagination method and queries as before once this works for you. Keep in mind this method does not have `start_time` nor `end_time` as parameters.